# Increment everytime i press + button

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm working on this Incrementor Decrementor program .. where First i enter a number and as i press + the entered number is incremented by 1 and decrements when i press - ... The problem is the value is getting incremented or decremented only once.

```
from tkinter import *

#******* Functions code ********

def add(event):
    a=float(enter.get())
    b=a+1
    labelresult=Label(root,text="Result : %2f"%b).grid(row=3,column=1)
    return


def sub(event):
    a=float(enter.get())
    b=a-1
    labelresult=Label(root,text="Result : %2f"%b).grid(row=3,column=1)
    return

#******* GUI code***********

root=Tk()
root.geometry('250x250')
root.title('Incrementor or Decrementor')

enter=IntVar()

label=Label(root,text="Skz.inc",bg='skyblue',fg='red').grid(row=0,column=1)

label=Label(root,text="enter a number").grid(row=1)

entry_1=Entry(root,textvariable=enter).grid(row=1,column=1)

button1=Button(root,text='+')
button1.grid(row=2,column=0)
button1.bind('<Button-1>',add)


button2=Button(root,text='-')
button2.grid(row=2,column=3)
button2.bind('<Button-1>',sub)

root.mainloop()
```

So the value which i entered should be increment or decrement each time i press either + or - button .
Example - when i enter 9 and press + the result should be 10 (works in my program) . Again on pressing + button the result should be 11 which is not the case in my code.
Help me out guys .. do modify and send me back the code.

Thanks

Comment: any reason to not use the [spinbox](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/spinbox.htm) widget ?

Comment: the value `enter` is incremented or decremented each time, the problem is that you're not updating it, you just output the result in the label `labelresult`. And they are not connected

Comment: Also, you should update the `labelresult` rather than creating a new one each time

Answer (score 2):

Each time you press <kbd>+</kbd> or <kbd>-</kbd> the function reads the value in the entry. You will have to update the value in the entry for every add or sub.

```
def add(event):
    a=float(enter.get())
    b=a+1
    labelresult.config(text="Result : %2f"%b)  # Update labelresult instead of 
                                               # creating a new label every time
    enter.set(b)   # Set entry to the new value
    return
```

You will have to create `labelresult` in the GUI code:

```
labelresult = Label(root)
labelresult.grid(row=3,column=1)
```

Comment: why not update `labelresult` too ? (if you add `print(len(root.children))` in the function, you see that all labels stay here, they are only overlayed)

Comment: I missed that, you were too fast. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much!! It worked perfectly but how to make the cursor(in entry box) disappear while incrementing or decrementing and also hide the value in the entry box which is newly set(like I want only the entered number to be displayed). Do send me the code after modification

And I'd like to learn django module can you help me out by suggesting best tutorials out there? which will help me in building an Online bakery system for my mini project.

Thank you

Comment: Ok, so you want the cursor to disappear. But when? How do you determine when a value is entered. Also, please google for answers before you ask, try to make it work and then tell us what you have tried. We do not write code for you, we help you to learn. Googling for solutions is something you will need to master if you are going to be a programmer. As for Django, I haven't used it. Google "Django tutorial".